# Remove the space of a hidden rectangle in footer of RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, expression, rdlc, reportviewer

I use RDLC Report, I can hide my rectangle* when is not the last page thank to Visibility properties and the expression :

```
=Iif(Globals!TotalPages = Globals!PageNumber, false, true )
```

But how can I do ( if it's possible...) to remove the space of my rectangle when is not the last page ?

*Rectangle is a panel with some information

Answer (score 1):

I put the rectangle at the end of my body after a tablix, and it solved my problem, I see the rectangle just at the last page and on the other pages the space of my rectangle is remove